# Compilation issue in spark scala script containing join on RDDs with 2 columns

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to compile the following script using sbt package command.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkConf, org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions
object CusMaxRevenue {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CusMaxRevenue")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ordersRDD = sc.textFile("/user/sk/sqoop_import/orders")
    val orderItemsRDD = sc.textFile("/user/sk/sqoop_import/order_items")

    // val ordersParsedRDD = ordersRDD.map( rec => ((rec.split(",")(0).toInt), (rec.split(",")(1),rec.split(",")(2)) ))
    val ordersParsedRDD = ordersRDD.map( rec => ((rec.split(",")(0).toInt), rec.split(",")(1) ))

    val orderItemsParsedRDD = orderItemsRDD.map(rec => ((rec.split(",")(1)).toInt, rec.split(",")(4).toFloat))

    val ordersJoinOrderItems = orderItemsParsedRDD.join(ordersParsedRDD)
}
}
```

I get the following error:

```
[info] Set current project to Customer with Max revenue (in build file:/home/sk/scala/app3/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/sk/scala/app3/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/sk/scala/app3/src/main/scala/CusMaxRevenue.scala:14: value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Float)]
[error]     val ordersJoinOrderItems = orderItemsParsedRDD.join(ordersParsedRDD)
[error]                                                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Sample Data:

```
--ordersParsedRDD
(1,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0)
(2,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0)
(3,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0)
(4,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0)
(5,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0)

--orderItemsParsedRDD
(9.98)
(2,199.99)
(2,250.0)
(2,129.99)
(4,49.98)
```

When i execute the statements individually on spark scala prompt the join seems to work.
PS: I had a few columns in the RDDs but inoder to investigate further i kept just the 2 but i still get the compilation issue !

Additional Info:
Content of my CusMaxRevenue.sbt file

```
name := "Customer with Max revenue"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1"
```

Comment: seems to be a problem of version conflict spark/scala. what is the scala version and spark version do you use?

Comment: @user1314742  . I got the following version from spark-shell prompt. This is the same version that i use in .sbt file
`scala> util.Properties.versionString
res32: String = version 2.10.4``

Comment: and in your sbt file? what is the version of spark-core?

Comment: The spark core version is sbt file is 1.2.1

Comment: could you paste the content of your sbt file? it seems that there is missing dependencies ( as seen in the error mention in your comment to the answer below)

Comment: The content of my SBT file  is :  `name := "Customer with Max revenue"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1" `

Comment: could you modify the spark dependecy to be as `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.1"`

Comment: Unfortunately after the change i get the same issue :  `[info] Set current project to Customer with Max revenue (in build file:/home/sk/scala/app3/)  
[info] Updating {file:/home/sk/scala/app3/}app3...  
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...  
[info] Done updating.  
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/sk/scala/app3/target/scala-2.10/classes...  
[error] /home/sk/scala/app3/src/main/scala/CusMaxRevenue.scala:8: not found: type SparkContext  
[error]     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)  
[error]                  ^  
[error] one error found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the import:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```

which bring all the implicit conversions.

Comment: Hi @Jean 
I changed the library inclusion statements to following:
`import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._`
`import org.apache.spark.SparkConf`
`import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions`


Now i get the following error:
`[error] /home/sk/scala/app3/src/main/scala/CusMaxRevenue.scala:8: not found: type SparkContext`
`[error]     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)`
`[error]                  ^`
`[error] one error found`
`[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed`

Comment: You still need ``org.apache.spark.SparkContext``, in addition to the ones you mentionned.

Comment: that solved the issue, i have the jar now.. thanks a Ton

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
val orderItemsParsedRDD = orderItemsRDD.map(rec => ( ((rec.split(",")(1).toInt), rec.split(",")(4).toFloat))
```